# Can't see the last two lines from serial buffer on tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to read a buffer from a serial com.
I am using the following methods but I never see the last 2 lines on my text area.
When I disconnect from the serial connection, the 2 lines suddenly appears.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with code?
Thank you.

Code:

```
# scrolled text box used to display the serial data

win.configure(background="gray14")

frame1 = tk.Frame(win,width=75, height=120,bg = '#ffffff',
                  borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame1) 
editArea = tk.Text(frame1, width=75, height=33, wrap="word",
                 yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,font("Helvetica",11),fg='#ffffff',
                   borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=0,background="gray34")
scrollbar.config(command=editArea.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
editArea.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
editArea.yview_pickplace("end")
editArea.see("end")
frame1.place(x=10,y=30)


# serial data callback function

def OnReceiveSerialData(message):
    str_message = message.decode("utf-8")
    editArea.insert("end", str_message)
    editArea.see(END)
```

Comment: `tkinter` is single threaded. Most likely your serial connection is blocking the main thread - try `threading.Thread` on your serial callback function.

Comment: thanks very much for your help